Keras - one-hot encoding - проблемы
Нужно через utils закодировать numpy массив с формой (200000,3,1), но при выполнении появляется ошибка
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-284cf0acd391> in <cell line: 23>()
     21 classes_in=['bal','bas','bnl','bns','wal','was','wnl','wns']
     22 
---> 23 input_data=to_categorical([classes_in.index(label) for label in input_data])
     24 
     25 #making output

<ipython-input-65-284cf0acd391> in <listcomp>(.0)
     21 classes_in=['bal','bas','bnl','bns','wal','was','wnl','wns']
     22 
---> 23 input_data=to_categorical([classes_in.index(label) for label in input_data])
     24 
     25 #making output

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

При прогоне массива такой же формы, но с меньшим количеством значений все кодируется без проблем.
Исходный массив данных закачивается из таблицы эксель, но никаких битых данных там нет.
В чем может быть причина?
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
input_data=np.array(['bal','bas','bnl','bns','wal','was','wnl','wns','bal','bas','bnl','bns','wal','was','wnl','wns','wns','wns'])
input_data.reshape(6,3,1)
classes_in=['bal','bas','bnl','bns','wal','was','wnl','wns']

input_data_n=to_categorical([classes_in.index(label) for label in input_data])


Полный стек-трейс ошибки поместите прямо в вопрос. Не нужно выдёргивать текст ошибки из трейса. Контекст, в котором происходит ошибка, очень важен. А может быть и так, что это ошибка вторичная, а первичная в чём-то другом вообще.

добавил ошибку в текст вопроса

А, ну я смог воспроизвести.  Ошибка именно здесь. Если у вас в input_data будет массив массивов, а не просто массив, то выйдет именно такая ошибка. Почитайте вот здесь варианты как закодировать строки https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56227671/how-can-i-one-hot-encode-a-list-of-strings-with-keras
